# Drupal Themes

Tags: drupal, xhtml, themes

Can anyone suggest a better place than drupal.org to find quality themes?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the commercial theme makers, like RoopleTheme or TopNotchThemes, you have at least two places to browse for Drupal themes:

- the [Drupal theme garden](http://themegarden.org/drupal6/) theme demo site
- the [D-Theme](http://d-theme.com/007_nigraphic_studio_theme) theme review site

Both sites allow you to try the theme, but D-Theme also includes critical reviews.

Beyond this, of course, your favorite search engine will provide you with a list of Drupal themes elsewhere

Comment: Thank you both for the help I would like to repay you for your assistance with some software if you would like.

Answer (score 0):

I think [monstertemplates](http://www.templatemonster.com/drupal-themes.php) has some good drupal themes.

Free themes: [Drupal2U](http://drupal2u.com/) or [AllDrupalThemes](http://alldrupalthemes.com/)

Regards,
Benedikt

Answer (score 0):

At templatemonster.com you can find some good themes for drupal.

At http://themehyve.com/ you can find all templatemonster drupal themes with a discount of 10%! Just enter the templatemonster theme #id